# How to only consider the first N cipher of an int number?

Tags: c, types, integer, numbers

I have an integer number, which can be codified on `3` or `4` ciphers (for example, `123`, `1234` and so on...) or can be codified on 7 or 8 cipher (for example, `1234567`, `12345678` and so on...).
Now, the problem is:
if the number is codified on 7 ciphers, I only need to save the first 3. For example:

```
1234567 -> 123
```

if the number is codified on 8 ciphers, I only need to save the first 4. For example:

```
12345678 -> 1234
```

How can I only save the first N cipher of the number into an other int value? Thank you everybody!
I thought about something like this:

```
int number = 12345678;
if(number>9999999){ //if the number is codified on 8 ciphers
...
}else if(number>9999 && number<10000000){ \\if the number is codified on 7 ciphers
...
}else{
...
}
```

Comment: Just `number / 10000`?

Comment: no, because if I divide the number by 10000, due to the numerical approximation, the first digits change

Comment: No, they will not. There is no "numerical approximation" in `int`. `int` is exact. It stores the exact value. Could you give an example? What do you mean? `12345678 / 10000` is always `1234`. (What can happen, is that `int` may be 16-bit. You should consider using `long`).

Comment: You could have a loop, and as long as `number` is greater than 9999, divide it by 10.

Comment: I think that what you call *cipher* could be called *digit*. Notice that [cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher) is related to cryptography. For that use (on Linux) [crypt(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html). Consider compiling with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then using the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use do while loop. I believe cipher codified only on 7 and 8. If you still continue you can keep adding the code. As far as I understood, i tried to put into code here,

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  long long n;
  int num=3;
  int count=0;
  printf("Enter an integer: ");
  scanf("%lld", &n);
  if(n>9999999)
  {
      num=4;
  }
  printf("Number of cipher: %d", num);
  // iterate at least once, then until n becomes 0
  // remove last digit from n in each iteration
  // increase count by 1 in each iteration
  do {
    n /= 10;
    count++;
  } while (count!=num);
  if(count==3)
  {
      n/=10;
  }
  printf("Number of cipher: %lld", n);
}
```